# issue in processing data from a csv file and a dictionary in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a `csv` file `file1.csv` whose sample structure is like this(the `state` below are abbreviations of `US states`):

```
companyid,state,amount
A,AL,609
A,AL,589
A,AL,915
A,AL,344
A,AL,813
A,AL,825
A,AL,825
A,AL,219
A,AL,778
A,AL,145
A,AL,983
A,AL,621
A,AR,339
A,AR,269
```

Notice that the data above is for multiple `companyid's` (records of company `A` followed by records of company `B` and so on) and within each company there are records for multiple `states`(you can see records for states `AL` followed by `AR` for company `A` above). In the data file for each `companyid` and for each `state` within that `companyid` there are `12 records`.

Also I have a python dictionary `dict1` whose structure is like this:

```
{'Mississippi': ['102738', '104143', '104046', '102727', '103769', '102865', '105348', '104399', '103016', '105377', '105184', '105829'], 'Oklahoma': ['166332', '167224', '168511', '175317', '171668', '176352', '178444', '179126', '179582', '182935', '186687', '184799'], 'Delaware': ['59254', '59357', '59248', '58559', '59715', '60559', '60829', '62160', '61094', '62375', '63646', '63908'], 'Minnesota': ['294611', '292213', '298997', '297042', '302542', '303040', '311457', '312043', '309764', '312677', '320114', '322264'],.....}
```

Here the `key` is the `state name` and values for that key are 12 numbers. Apart from that I have function `func1(list1,list2)` which takes two `list` parameters `list1` and `list2`.

Now what I want do is that for each `companyid` from the csv file and then for each `state` within that `companyid`, form the two lists - `list1` will have 12 records from the csv file (Notice that for each `companyid` and for each `state` within that `companyid` there are exactly 12 records in csv file) and `list2` which will have 12 records from the dictionary `dict1` for that `state`(the state needs to mapped). These two lists needs to passed to the function `func1()` each time so that the `func1()` is called each time for each company and for each distinct state within that company once.

One thing to note that the `state` in csv file are in abbreviated format while in dictionary `dict1` they are in full format. For this I have created a separate dictionary which has following structure:

```
states = {
        'AK': 'Alaska',
        'AL': 'Alabama',
        'AR': 'Arkansas',
        'AS': 'American Samoa',
        'AZ': 'Arizona',
        'CA': 'California',
        'CO': 'Colorado',
        'CT': 'Connecticut',
        'DC': 'District of Columbia',
        'DE': 'Delaware',
        'FL': 'Florida',
        'GA': 'Georgia',
        'GU': 'Guam',
        'HI': 'Hawaii',
        'IA': 'Iowa',
        'ID': 'Idaho',
        'IL': 'Illinois',
          .
          .
          .
```

I am having difficulty in understanding how to do it? Can anyone help me in this?

**NOTE:** The desired structure that I want is:

```
for each companyid and for each state in that companyid in csv file:
     list1 = 12 records from the csv file
     list2 = 12 records from the dictionary after mapping the abbreviated state through the state dictionary that I have
     call func1(list1,list2)
```

Comment: Can you show how the desired output should look like?

Comment: @JoeR as I have mentioned that for each `companyid` in csv file and for each `state` within that `companyid` I want to form two lists - list1 will have 12 records from the csv file (Notice that for each companyid and for each state within that companyid there are exactly 12 records in csv file) and list2 which will have 12 records from the dictionary dict1 for that state(the state needs to mapped) and then pass there two lists to the `func1(list1,list2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first task is to collect your CSV data in a format that is easily referenced by company, then state:

```
import csv

company_data = {}  # empty dictionary

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    next(reader) # skips the header
    for row in reader:
        company_states = company_data.setdefault(row[0], {})
        state_data = company_states.setdefault(row[1], [])
        state_data.append(row[2])
        company_data[row[0]][row[1]] = state_data
```

At the end of the above loop, our dictionary looks like:

```
>>> company_data['A']['AL']
['609','589','915',...,'621']
```

Next, we need to pull the numbers from the other dictionary to pass to our function.

```
for company, data in company_data.iteritems():
    # Data is now  the inner dictionary
    for state_abbrev, values in data.iteritems():
         func1(values, dict1[states[state_abbrev]])
```

Comment: When I do `print company_data` i get this - `{'PU': {'NC': ['107'......`. There is no companyid with `PU` as id. Is this python specific?

Comment: No, its coming from your file.

Answer (score 0):

This can achieved using the Python `csv` library. I have added some dummy data for `Alabama` to show some suitable output:

```
import csv, itertools

dict1 = {'Alabama' : ['1','2','3'], 'Mississippi': ['102738', '104143', '104046', '102727', '103769', '102865', '105348', '104399', '103016', '105377', '105184', '105829'], 'Oklahoma': ['166332', '167224', '168511', '175317', '171668', '176352', '178444', '179126', '179582', '182935', '186687', '184799'], 'Delaware': ['59254', '59357', '59248', '58559', '59715', '60559', '60829', '62160', '61094', '62375', '63646', '63908'], 'Minnesota': ['294611', '292213', '298997', '297042', '302542', '303040', '311457', '312043', '309764', '312677', '320114', '322264']}

states = {
    'AK': 'Alaska',
    'AL': 'Alabama',
    'AR': 'Arkansas',
    'AS': 'American Samoa',
    'AZ': 'Arizona',
    'CA': 'California',
    'CO': 'Colorado',
    'CT': 'Connecticut',
    'DC': 'District of Columbia',
    'DE': 'Delaware',
    'FL': 'Florida',
    'GA': 'Georgia',
    'GU': 'Guam',
    'HI': 'Hawaii',
    'IA': 'Iowa',
    'ID': 'Idaho',
    'IL': 'Illinois'}

def func1(list1, list2):
    print list1
    print list2
    print

with open('file1.csv', 'r') as f_file1:
    csv_file1 = csv.reader(f_file1)
    header = next(csv_file1)

    for list1 in iter(lambda: list(itertools.islice(csv_file1, 12)), []):
        list2 = [[company_id, dict1.get(states.get(state, '<unknown>'), ['<unknown>']), amount] for company_id, state, amount in list1]
        func1(list1, list2)
```

This would display the following output from `func1()`:

```
[['A', 'AL', '609'], ['A', 'AL', '589'], ['A', 'AL', '915'], ['A', 'AL', '344'], ['A', 'AL', '813'], ['A', 'AL', '825'], ['A', 'AL', '825'], ['A', 'AL', '219'], ['A', 'AL', '778'], ['A', 'AL', '145'], ['A', 'AL', '983'], ['A', 'AL', '621']]
[['A', ['1', '2', '3'], '609'], ['A', ['1', '2', '3'], '589'], ['A', ['1', '2', '3'], '915'], ['A', ['1', '2', '3'], '344'], ['A', ['1', '2', '3'], '813'], ['A', ['1', '2', '3'], '825'], ['A', ['1', '2', '3'], '825'], ['A', ['1', '2', '3'], '219'], ['A', ['1', '2', '3'], '778'], ['A', ['1', '2', '3'], '145'], ['A', ['1', '2', '3'], '983'], ['A', ['1', '2', '3'], '621']]

[['A', 'AR', '339'], ['A', 'AR', '269']]
[['A', ['<unknown>'], '339'], ['A', ['<unknown>'], '269']]
```

The script will give you `<unknown>` if a state or entry in `dict1` is missing. Tested using Python 2.7.